# How many initial Cassandra nodes I need to start?

Tags: database, cassandra, nodes, replication-factor

I am ought to develop a new application and I decided to use Apache Cassandra database. Because of the low money budget I can't rent a bug amount of servers. For the begining I have a VPS plan to host my first cassandra node.

Is it ok to start with only one machine and then scale to others? I mean the replication factor will be 0 because I have only one node.
What I have to do? What I have to mention?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the phase of development, you can start with 1 node and as you move along, you can add more nodes to your cluster.

Remember, with a single node you have a point of failure, if the node goes down you might loose all the data. As far as replication factor goes, its can be changed when you add more nodes to your cluster.

So start with one node and replication factor of 1 (which is default).